# Pine Script - Not Displaying input.int options data, it worked yesterday?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

is anyone else finding problems with their input.int(... , options=[1,2,3,4,5]) not displaying any data within the drop down list? You can still drop the menu down and select an "option", it all works fine, except there is no visible text/data contained within the drop down menu options?

It worked fine yesterday and I haven't updated the code since then. Also, I tried creating a new little indicator script just containing the following code, got the same problem, no data within the drop down menu!?

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
plot(close)

test = input.int(defval=5, title="Test DD", options=[1,2,3,4,5])
```

I've tried a different Tradingview account and a different browser, no luck. Please help!
Thanks

[No Data within Drop Down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3019.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support team says that this is a recent bug. The fix is in progress.

Comment: Thanks - I raised a ticket with them yesterday, I've had confirmation that they've passed the issue onto the relevant team; awaiting further updates.

Answer (score 1):

Your script works perfectly on my tradingview, 
I think it is more a problem linked to your browser, try to clean your browser and restart it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I've tried with Firefox, Chrome and Edge and am getting the same issue! I've been investigating and am not the only one reporting this problem at the moment.
It's happening with certain scripts (but not all) when using input.int or input.float with the options=[] parameter.